# Error while running React app (npm start)

Tags: reactjs, npm, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Getting this error while running react app. Was working fine yesterday with the same code.

```
 PS C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\portfolio\portfolio-website> npm start

> portfolio@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start  

C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\portfolio\portfolio-website\node_modules\pretty-error\lib\defaultStyle.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\portfolio\portfolio-website\node_modules\pretty-error\lib\PrettyError.js:8:16)
```

Comment: The content of that file is obviously not JavaScript, it must have been corrupted somehow. Have you tried a reinstall of the dependencies?

Comment: I am actually new to react & node 
So should I run "npm install" to reinstall?

Comment: add your package json script part

Comment: Delete the node_modules/ directory, in case other files are also corrupted, then npm install.

Comment: Worked by reinstalling node_modules. Thanks, everyone!